# Shutdown windows with graphical prompt for user

Tags: windows-7, command-line, shutdown

We manage about 60 distributes Windows 7 PCs using Powershell Remoting. After our work is done, we'd like the computers to shut down: Doing this is easy using the shutdown /s /t X command. But sometimes users are actively working on the machines at the time we send the shutdown command, so it would be good if the shutdown warning would offer the option of canceling the shutdown.

Is this possible with the shutdown command? Are there other tools that allow this?

Answer (score 2):

From `shutdown /?`:

```
No args    Display help. This is the same as typing /?.
/?         Display help. This is the same as not typing any options.
/i         Display the graphical user interface (GUI).
           This must be the first option.
/l         Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options.
/s         Shutdown the computer.
/r         Shutdown and restart the computer.
/g         Shutdown and restart the computer. After the system is
           rebooted, restart any registered applications.
/a         Abort a system shutdown.
           This can only be used during the time-out period.
/p         Turn off the local computer with no time-out or warning.
           Can be used with /d and /f options.
/h         Hibernate the local computer.
           Can be used with the /f option.
/e         Document the reason for an unexpected shutdown of a computer.
/m \\computer Specify the target computer.
/t xxx     Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.
           The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), with a default of 30.
           If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is
           implied.
/c "comment" Comment on the reason for the restart or shutdown.
           Maximum of 512 characters allowed.
/f         Force running applications to close without forewarning users.
           The /f parameter is implied when a value greater than 0 is
           specified for the /t parameter.
/d [p|u:]xx:yy  Provide the reason for the restart or shutdown.
           p indicates that the restart or shutdown is planned.
           u indicates that the reason is user defined.
           If neither p nor u is specified the restart or shutdown is
           unplanned.
           xx is the major reason number (positive integer less than 256).
           yy is the minor reason number (positive integer less than 65536).
```

`/t`, `/c` and `/a` are the options of interest here.

`/t` provides a timeout
`/a` allows a user to cancel a shutdown process *while waiting for timeout*
`/c` allows you to supply a message (`/d` affects the logs)

Possible solution - In the comment, state that the shutdown can be cancelled by running `shutdown /a` within the timeout.

Do consider email to users describing this in more detail.

Another solution would be to run a short script that gives the user the option of postponing or authorising the shutdown, at which point it would wait, or run the shutdown command.

Edit: Found pretty much the same question on SO, answered here: 
[A batch file for shutdown with prompt option to abort it and re-run after a certain time of amount?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11180295/4022608)